# Image quality in Chrome is bad compared to other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, image-quality

For some weeks now image quality has been terrible in chrome. I've checked the flags to make sure nothing has been enabled by accident. I've also reinstalled chrome and cleared the search history.

Here is the same image open in chrome(on the left) and in internet explorer:
http://i.imgur.com/7MEdwt4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recognized as a bug, and there's now a workaround provided in response #62: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=492379#c62

Answer (score 2):

Disable *"Use hardware acceleration when available"* in settings.

[image: Refer to the picture]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1 . Pulse "Ctrl + 0" (zero) Its return to 100% web size.

2 . Dont resize image with styles or width attribute. Design your image to the exact size you need.

Its works for me. ;)